# How to change extended windows file attributes via Powershell without using attrib.exe?

Tags: powershell, winapi, filesystems

This seems to be a quite simple question, yet googling gave me nothing.
Here is the error (PS 5.1, win 10.0.14393 x64):

```
Set-ItemProperty $myFileInfo -Name Attributes -Value ([System.IO.FileAttributes]::Temporary)
The attribute cannot be set because attributes are not supported. Only the following attributes can be set: Archive, Hidden, Normal, ReadOnly, or System.
```

`attrib.exe` seems to support most of `System.IO.FileAttributes`. Unfortunately is does not seem to work with files referenced using FileSystem PSDrives. That is what I am using extensively.

Making wrapper for [SetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) kernel API call would be the last resort.

Am I missing any other [more simple] ways setting these extended file attributes?

PS. Apart from `[System.IO.FileAttributes]::Temporary` I am interested in setting `[System.IO.FileAttributes]::NotContentIndexed`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can edit the Attributes property of a `[FileInfo]` object directly. For example, if you wanted to exclude all files in the C:\Temp folder from being content indexed, you could do this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp | ForEach{
    $_.Attributes = $_.Attributes + [System.IO.FileAttributes]::NotContentIndexed
}
```

That would get each file, and then add the `[System.IO.FileAttributes]::NotContentIndexed` attribute to the existing attributes. You could probably filter the files to make sure that the attribute doesn't already exist before trying to add it, since that may throw errors (I don't know, I didn't try).

**Edit:** As noted by @grunge this does not work in Windows Server 2012 R2. Instead what you have to do is reference the `value__` property, which is the bitwise flag value, and add the bitwise flag for `NotContentIndexed`. This should work for you on any Windows OS:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp | ForEach{
    $_.Attributes = [System.IO.FileAttributes]($_.Attributes.value__ + 8192)
}
```

Comment: on Windows Server 2012R2 i only get the error:
[System.IO.FileAttributes] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Comment: To get the Value, use: `[system.io.fileattributes]::Temporary.Value__`

Comment: When I try to set attributes for a file with corrupted attributes 4227088 nothing is changed and no error is displayed. Ex. `(Get-Item -path BadAttrs.txt).Attributes=0` followed by `(Get-Item -path BadAttrs.txt).Attributes` shows the original value.

Comment: Update for my comment about not changing corrupted attributes: I get the same silent failure with the Win32 API `SetFileAttributesW`.

Comment: If you are concerned about corrupted attributes you could add checking to your script to record the old value, and check the new value against it to make sure it has changed.

Comment: This won't work for things like encryption that appear to be a truly read-only flag set by some other mechanism.